# python - Substrings which contain only 'a', 'b' or 'c'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I was coding for [this problem.](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/substring/)

> Maggu has just joined play school. His teacher taught him A,a,B,b,C,c. He is much fascinated with these letters and now he is looking only for those strings which contains these letters only. But as i said he is a little guy he cant calculate the number of such sub-strings alone. Find the number of such strings.

```
def substrings(string):
    for size in range(1, len(string)+1):
        for index in range(len(string)-size+1):
            yield string[index:index+size]

l = []

for x in range(int(raw_input())):
    l.append(raw_input().lower())

not_ = 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for string in l:
    count = 0
    for substr in substrings(string):
        if all(letter not in substr for letter in not_):
            count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

I realized that we can reduce the problem to lower case. I've wrote the code but it is not efficient for large strings. And by large I mean exceptionally large strings. I have realized that it is the `substrings` function that is taking up a lot of time. How may I reduce the time consumption of the `substrings` function? Can I replace it with some other code?

Thanks.

Comment: One improvement with python 2. U should use `xrange` instead of `range`. It's more performance for large number

Comment: @julivico Good idea. `xrange` is much faster than `range` in Python 2.

Comment: what do u want to do with the code in `for x in range(int(raw_input())):
    l.append(raw_input().lower())`

Comment: @julivico It takes the input from the site. I am inserting the string in lowercase itself.

Comment: You could replace all `abc` with an empty string and check the length against 0. I don't see the need to generate substrings

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this is exponential is because you iterate over the same string for different window lengths (up to len(string)). This is a job for regular expressions, which will simply make one pass over your string to find any sequences that contain the letters a, b, c, A, B, and C in succession at least once.

After you have found these sequences, you can calculate their arithmetic progression to count how many substrings each of those contain. To understand why we have to use arithmetic progression, consider we have found the sequence 'abc' somewhere in the big string. The actual substrings of this sequence are 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', and 'c'. Basically, for a string of length n, we can construct n substrings starting from the first letter, n-1 substrings starting from the second letter, ..., and 1 substring starting from the last letter.

```
import re

def count_substrings(string):
    found = re.findall('[a-cA-C]+', string)
    count = 0
    for f in found:
        length = len(f)
        count += length * (length + 1) / 2
    return count
```

For the example shown in the link

```
>>> strings = ['AXa', 'ABC', 'AXBC', 'AaBbCc', 'XxYyZz']
>>> for s in strings:
...    print(count_substrings(s))

2
6
4
21
0
```

---

If you want to implement what `re.findall()` does yourself, you can try the following.

```
found = []
substring = ''
for s in string:
    if s in 'abcABC':
        substring += s
    else:
        # if we had a sequence going, it just ended, so add it to our found list
        if substring:
            found.append(substring)
            substring = ''
# make sure to append the last sequence we had been working on
if substring:
    found.append(substring)
```